# How to add bootstrap date time picker in mvc view

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, datetimepicker

Please anyone can provide me live example that load the latest bootstrap date time picker in MVC view.

My project already has:
- jQuery.
- Bootstrap js.
- Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: Probably your code is ok just add css and js of either bootstrap or jquery for date picker

Answer (score 0):

May be this will helps you. Very flexible and ease to set.

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Or

http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Or try this - html5 date input

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label>Date</label>
 <input type="date" name="bday" max="3000-12-31" min="1000-01-01" class="form-control">
</div>
```